# Is it possible to access variables and their values in a running program (c++)

Tags: c++, windows

Is it somehow possible to access variables which another program is using while its runnning using c++?
for example i have a program which always changes the variable `a` by 1, and i want to create another program and access the `a` variable and its value.

Comment: The only possibility I can see is that these programmes correspond to different threads of a same programme

Comment: So its not possbile in all cases but only when the programs somehow already can comunicate from the beginning?

Comment: In my opinion no. Of course there is always the possibility to communicate through files from example, but it must be planned since the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access variables in another program, provided:

- The variable is not on the "stack".
- The variable is not in a register.
- The program is running *at the same time* as your program.
- The memory page that the variable resides in is in memory and hasn't
  been "paged out" to the hard drive (i.e. virtual memory).

Usually, variables that need to be shared between programs are placed into "shared memory", an area of memory that two or more processes can have access to.

Shared variables need to have a protection scheme so that only one process writes to the variable and the variable is not read while it is written to.

You'll need to search the internet for "c++ windows shared memory example", as the concept is to large to fit into a StackOverflow answer.

**Edit: Stack Variables**
Technically, you can access a variable that is on another program's stack, provided that the stack is in an addressable area in memory (some processors have internal stack that is not addressable by an external program).

The issue is timing.  Many programs written in C++ place local variables on the stack at the beginning of a function or statement block (like an `if` statement or `while` loop).  The variables will disappear after execution leaves the scope of the statement block.  Thus your program will have to have very good timing to figure out when the variable is on the stack (and hopefully your program is running at this time).  Although, the OS can swap out the other program to the hard drive while your program runs in the same memory space.  In this case, you won't be able to access the other program's variables.

**Register Variables**
Very few processors have registers that are memory mapped.  Most processor's registers do not have an address.  Also, your program maybe using the same registers.  In general, the operating system will "freeze" the other program, writing its registers and stack to an area in memory or on the hard drive.  Your program will then be loaded into memory (a.k.a. your program's variables and stack space will be restored) and your program executed where it left off.  This shows you the difficulty in time and access for variables in other programs.